# How do I get the size of the canvas prior to onDraw()

Tags: android, random, android-canvas

I've found some related questions, no exclusive answer;

In my game, I create an object. The object (class) takes a random position on the screen :
 `public float X=Rnd.nextInt(400);`. I would like to replace the 400 max value with a randomizer.

It should put the object somewhere on the X, following these rules :

left margin of canvas + 10 < X < right margin of canvas - 20

But.. the onDraw() has not yet been called. So I can't do a getWidth() on the canvas.

How should I solve this? i.e. what is the method for checking the size of the canvas before onDraw is called? (or should I maybe use screensize? if so, how?)

Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

you can get ctx with getApplicationContext()

and if you are using an api < 13 you should use:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Comment: Thanks! `Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();`

Solved it. I used it in the class that extends the SurfaceView. Then with : `width = display.getWidth();` I'm able to put the width in a publicly accessible int.

Comment: ByteMe, thanks to your answer I was able to write https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=happyworx.nl.Applez . Thank you!

Comment: I don't recommend use getContext() or getApplicationContext(), because Activity is instance of Context, for example: Context context = this; (where this is activity)

Answer (score 0):

You should never use Canvas.getWidth() because it doesn't return what you think it does. This method returns the width of the entire Canvas, which usually corresponds to the window width. Just use View.getWidth() instead.

Comment: How do I do that? In the apple class? In the maingamepanel class? I get a static reference error. My  MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback... please elaborate on how to do this. thnx

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for getting screen dimension:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Comment: Sry, Praful, I don't get it. I've got the MainGamePanel and the class ("apple") in the class, I want to use the randomizer. in the MainGamePanel, I override onDraw(). Where should I put your code? what is ctx.getSystemService? getSize is undefined for the type display?

Comment: ctx the the context and see [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize(android.graphics.Point)) for get size java doc..